# Install oracle-java7-installer showing error

Tags: apt, java, 16.04

I tried running the command in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-set-default
```

but it's showing an error:

[image]

How can I install this package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle JDK 6 and 7 are not available by default in Ubuntu 16.04 repositories and requires you to add repositories for the same as follows:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

$ sudo apt-get update
```

You may now run your command and enjoy using Java.

If you get ***error while installing ppa:repository***, you will need to ***re-install ca certificates*** as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

Once this is done try running first two commands again.

Comment: After running this command : "$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java", I am getting some errors : ERROR: '~webupd8team' user or team does not exist.
Error: 'ppa:webupd8team/java' invalid

Comment: Probably your ca certificates are not able to verify the authenticity of your ppa through SSL connection. Possible solution is to re-install ca certificates. I am updating my answer for the same.

Comment: I tried reinstalling ca certificate but after that the same error is coming.

Answer (score 4):

As of March 22, 2019, it appears that `oracle-java7-installer` is no longer available from the `ppa:webupd8team/java` upstream repo (it could be that it got move to a different archive repo).

Alternatively, you can install `oracle-java8-installer` instead if you have the apt repo setup properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Make sure you have added the PPA first, then update your package list and then install your package.

Answer (score 0):

Install Oracle Java 13:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java13-installer
```